# RMOND theory and Schwarzschild metric

Tags: general-relativity, astrophysics

In a recent paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.00082, two authors propose a new model (RMOND) which seems succesful to explain many cosmological data. Obviously, the GR theory must have as classical limit the modified equations of gravity of RMOND. Is the Schwarzschild metric modified by this new theory? And if the answer is 'yes', how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course the Schwarzschild metric is modified by this new RMOND theory.

Newton's gravity is the weak field limit of Schwarzschild metric. And MOND is a modification of Newton's gravity. Therefore any relativistic extension of MOND theory (including RMOND) has to modify the Schwarzschild metric at least in the weak field limit.

The paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.00082 you cited focuses on the FLRW metric, since it discuses the RMOND's cosmological consequences.

If you are interest in the modified Schwarzschild metric formula, you can refer to equation (16) of another paper by the same author (Tom Złosnik): https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.3519

Comment: I haven't looked into the paper, but it's not automatically necessary that a new theory modify a particular solution (for instance, the modifying terms could have a zero solution for the case of spherical symmetry, or the Einstein-Maxwell equations having a Q=0 black hole solution.)

Comment: Let's be specific, by "the modifying terms could have a zero solution", do you mean the new theory recovers Newton gravity at weak field limit in your "instance"?

Comment: I'm saying (not for this theory), that just because the underlying equation is different than Einstein's equation, that it is still possible to have "the swarzschild metric" as a solution to this other equation.  For a trivial example, like how Einstein-Maxwell theory has the exact schwarzschild solution as a solution, or how a freely falling radially infalling observer in Schwarzschild has the same equation for $r(\tau)$ that you would get for $r(t)$ in Newtonian theory.

Comment: like, if the general RMond solution for spherically symmetric matter is something like schwarzschild + (iintegration constant) * (parity violating metric), then exact schwarzschild is a solution.

Comment: Is the general RMond solution for spherically symmetric matter something like schwarzschild + (iintegration constant) * (parity violating metric)?

Comment: As I said, I haven't looked at this particular solution.  I'm just saying that "the base equations are different" is not a sufficient condition for the end solutions to be different.

Comment: So you are not sure whether or not the particular solution offered by RMOND is exactly schwarzschild?

Comment: Again, (theory A modifies theory B) does not imply (Solution X to theory A is different from Solution Y to theory B), which is the argument you make above.  That is usually true, but it is not always true.

Comment: Again, this post is talking about RMOND, and let us talk about RMOND specifically. So for RMOND you are not sure whether or not the particular solution offered by RMOND is exactly schwarzschild?

Comment: Rephrase your argument in the answer above to be about RMOND specifically, rather than make a generic statement that is usually, but not always, true, and then applying that to RMOND.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. If you were White House speaker, I would have no problem :) But here is a physics forum ;)

Comment: You're not addressing the issue I'm raising.  If you said, "if canaries were dogs, then RMond has to alter Schwarzschild", it would be a formally true statement, but physically useless.  In physics, if you use wrong arguments in your line of reasoning, then the line of reasoning falls apart.  Whether or not your conclusion is true has nothing to do with whether your reasoning is valid.

Comment: Which is the "if canaries were dogs" statement I made? Please be specific by using quote, not paraphrasing.

Comment: "Newton's gravity is the weak field limit of Schwarzschild metric. And MOND is a modification of Newton's gravity. Therefore any relativistic extension of MOND theory (including RMOND) has to modify the Schwarzschild metric at least in the weak field limit."

Not all modifications of GR have to modify the Schwarzschild metric.

Comment: I am not talking about "all modifications of GR". I am talking about MOND and RMOND (as relativistic extension of MOND theory ) in specific. Does MOND modify the Schwarzschild metric in the weak field limit?